# loop through php array alphabetically

Tags: php

I have a PHP Loop that loops through data, i want to be able to echo all of this data alphabetically.

i currently use an array:

```
$output[]=array();
foreach($WHM_Servers as $whm) {
    foreach($server->list_accounts() as $ret) {
            $output[]= '<tr class="notfirst">
            <td>'.$ret["domain"].'</td>
            <td>'.$ret["user"].'</td>
            <td>'.CompanyInfoLookup($result["customer"], 'company').'</td>
            <td>'.$ret["startdate"].'</td>
            <td>'.$ret["starttime"].'</td>
            <td>'.$ret["disklimit"].'</td>
            <td>'.$ret["diskused"].'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
}
```

would i be able to add a key in the array and then echo the array alphabetically from the keys

Comment: Alphabetically by what?

Comment: i would like it to be by the $ret["name"];

Comment: using this code, it just displays as the array is created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few different ways to do this, I chose to write a user defined sort function.

```
$accounts = array();
$accounts[]['name'] = "Tom";
$accounts[]['name'] = "Frank";
$accounts[]['name'] = "Zed";
$accounts[]['name'] = "Aaron";

function compareNames($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($accounts, "compareNames");

var_dump($accounts);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Aaron"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Frank"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Tom"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Zed"
  }
}
```

This is a standalone example. To apply it to your example, you need to store the data: `$accounts = $server->list_accounts()`, sort it: `usort($accounts, "compareNames");`, and then pass it in to your loop: `foreach($accounts as $ret) {`